# Is there a jailbreak for iPod Touch 2g running 3.1.1?

Tags: ipod-touch, jailbreak

If I upgrade my iPod touch from 3.0.1 to 3.1.1, will I re-jail it?

Is there a redsn0w that will recognize and modify the IPSW for 3.1.1

I tried redsn0w 0.80 and it didn't recognize the firmware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably a good idea to start at the source: http://blog.iphone-dev.org/

There's no reason to check elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

1. There is not currently a 3.1 jailbreak.
2. There is no 3.0.1 for iPod touch. 3.0.1 fixed an SMS bug. iPod Touch has no SMS therefore no bug.
3. They're on 3.1.1 already? One day and 3.1 already needs a bugfix? Wow. (EDIT: Explained by this answer: [Is there a jailbreak for iPod Touch 2g running 3.1.1?](https://superuser.com/questions/39098/is-there-a-jailbreak-for-ipod-touch-2g-running-3-1-1/39142#39142))